# How to use Resources.resx in jQuery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, resources, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I would like to validate some form with jQuery Validation Plugin. Everything wortks fine, until when I want to use messages from Resources files.

It's my code:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        test1: {
            required: true,
        },
    messages: {
        test1: {
        required: "simple string works",
    },
});
```

I've tried to put

```
'@Html.Raw(Resources.testRes)'
'@Resources.testRes'
'Resources.testRes'
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the client and a .resx exists on the server, so it may not have access to it, depending on how you've organised your code. What server code are you using? ASP.NET, webforms, MVC? Where is that script? In a seperate .js file? In a <script> tag in a view?

Comment: I use ASP.NET MVC and validator file is in separete file

Comment: So when a page is requested, the action will build a view and the script bundle or <script> will send the .js file down, so when it's executing on the client, it won't have access to the .resx file. Have a look at some of these questions http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resx+js

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've just put my validator to my view file and it's works.

Comment: I've elaborated and put some details in a proper answer. Inline js is a bit of a messy approach and can give you headaches down the line, so have a look at some way to encapsulate it properly, e.g. a reference js file, maybe generated from the resx file if you'll be using the strings on the client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When page is requested in ASP.NET MVC, the action (if it has a ViewResult) will render the view and the script bundle or `<script src="path">` (from the view or its layout) will cause the browser to make another request for the .js file when it's processing the html sent in the response.

When this js is executing on the client, it won't have access to the .resx file, so any attempts to use razor (or aspx) will simply be invalid js.

If you include your `<script></script>` inline inside the view, it will be rendering on the server and you will have a reference to the resx file and your previous approaches will work.

Since you are composing inline javascript, this is somewhat messy, so consider another partial view as of your layout that interacts with the resx in this way to encapsulate all of this, or better yet a .js reference file that contains the messages.

There are some other [stackoverflow questions about js and resx](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=resx+js) for more details.